# Would wearing a yin/yang bracelet be avodah zarah?

Tags: avodah-zarah

Just as the question says, I wonder if wearing a [yin-yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang) bracelet would be assur

Comment: It might help to add more details on yin/yang. Is that a deity? Are people worshipping the yin/yang? Don't assume readers of the site are specialists of the yin/yang....

Comment: According to *AskTheRav* which is affiliated with the Beis Din of Crown Heights, Brooklyn, NY, and with the Va’ad Hakohol of Crown Heights - https://asktherav.com/12497-is-the-popular-chinese-yin-yang-symbol-a-symbol-of-avodah-zarah/ it is to be regarded as a philosophy and not avoda zara

Comment: There is a general principle of “not following in their ways” which could be relevant depending upon the individual and their circumstances. But as a whole, it’s worth remembering that in particular the wisdoms of the East (Asia) were gifts given from Avraham to his children from Keturah. They have their origins in the Wisdom of the Torah.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I don't think there is a reliable source for that. The yin-yang concept of balance is not part of Jewish thinking and is false.

Comment: @N.T. If you mean the concept of the “gifts” given by Abraham to his children from Keturah, this is mentioned in midrash. It’s definitely “reliable”. The “Yin-Yang” concept of balance has its source in the innovation of “male-female” which appears in parshat Bereshit. This pertains to the subject of Maaseh Bereshit in kabbalistic nomenclature like is mentioned by Rambam in Mishneh Torah, Hilchot Yesodei HaTorah. It too is rooted in the Wisdom of the Torah.

Comment: @N.T. Because they are currently unknown to you, doesn’t mean they are unknown. Your comment that male/female (in terms of kabbalah) are very different only emphasizes that there is a great deal you haven’t seen or don’t understand. My statement is not a criticism, only an observation. Try to keep an open mind and continue learning. Shavuah tov and blessings only.